# Disabled iPhone 4S after restore

Tags: iphone, restore

iPhone 4S disabled after a number of passcode incorrect entries.  I followed instructions to hook it up to an iTunes account etc and then to restore it to original settings.  The screen that no appears is iPhone disabled, emergency calls only.  There is a valid sim card in the phone.  The error that came up after the restore was 'could not connect phone to iTunes as valid passcode required'  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When the phone initially said disabled, you could have just left it untouched for a few hours and it will give you the option to try the passcode again, normally has a count down timer to when you can retry the passcode.

Anyhow, you can restore the phone using the DFU mode, hold down the home and the power button until screen goes off then immediately release the power button whilst still holding down the home button, make sure the phone is connected to the computer and have iTunes open when doing this.

The screen will remain black, but you should see the iPhone appear in iTunes where you can restore it.